# REDHAWK IDE 1.9 runs out of memory and has to be shutdown

Tags: eclipse, redhawksdr

I am using REDHAWK 1.9. While doing the development of C++ component, the IDE gives the following popup errors. This happens on a regular basis. If developing a C++ component it happens multiple times a day.

'Update Monitor' has encountered a problem. An internal error occurred during:  Update Monitor.

Another popup gives the following:

An out of memory error has occurred. Consult the 'Running the Eclipse' section of the readme file for information on preventing this kind of error in the future. You are recommended to exit the workbench. Subsequent errors may happen and may terminate the workbench without warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this may be related to [Eclipse Bug #400073](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400073)

Particularly, see [Comment #25](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400073#c25):

Boost libraries are used within REDHAWK components and devices, and the R1.9.0 IDE uses CDT version 8.1.2

That thread also lists a couple work arounds including:
"A workaround for me was decreasing the indexers absolute cache limits from 64MB to 32MB, though I don't know if this will work in general. You may find the settings at Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Indexer" from [Comment #23](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400073#c23)

You could also try adjusting additional preferences within the indexer page, "Index source files not included in the build" and "Index unused headers" could be unchecked. This can be done on a workspace level or a per project level.

As a last resort, you could try a new workspace or disabling the indexer entirely.